# android : SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique

Tags: android, sqlite, replace

I am getting this exception while trying to add an entry to table where the primary key is already in the table.

I have added the rule ON CONFLICT REPLACE. So is it not expected to replace the row when there is a duplicate entry than giving the exception.

(_id integer primary key,"...... (_id )ON CONFLICT REPLACE)");

Comment: Try changing the syntax. Add the constraint with the field declaration : (_id integer primary key on conflict replace,...);
If that doesn't work try (_id integer primary key,...... UNIQUE (_id ) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);

Comment: If Hbibna's advice above doesn't help, consider posting some more code to highlight the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using INSERT clause, use instead INSERT OR REPLACE.

Comment: tried that but throws an exception...
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INSERT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE table_contact ( _cid integer primary key , contactName TEXT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (_cid) ON CONFLICT INSERT OR REPLACE);

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the way you're defining the table. WHat is your unique ID? How it is managed (by your code/auto increment)?